# Что я делаю неверно? (Задача с Codewars 6 kyu)

Tags: python, рекурсия, числа

**Условия задачи:**

Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

**For example:**

```
persistence(39) # returns 3, because 3*9=27, 2*7=14, 1*4=4
                # and 4 has only one digit
                  
persistence(999) # returns 4, because 9*9*9=729, 7*2*9=126,
                 # 1*2*6=12, and finally 1*2=2

persistence(4) # returns 0, because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

**Мое решение данной задачи (у меня в IDE все условия выполняются):**

```
class Counter(object):
    counter = 0


def persistence(n):
    s = str(n)
    if len(s) > 1:
        Counter.counter += 1
        num = int(s[0])
        for x in range(1, len(s)):
            num *= int(s[x])
        return persistence(num)
    else:
        return Counter.counter
```

[image: Тесты]

```
test.it("Basic tests")
test.assert_equals(persistence(39), 3)
test.assert_equals(persistence(4), 0)
test.assert_equals(persistence(25), 2)
test.assert_equals(persistence(999), 4)
```

Comment: вы каунтер не обнуляете

Comment: @Интик Ну так в этом и фишка, я даже написал для него отдельный класс, чтобы он не обнулялся при повторном вызове рекурсивной функции, иначе он на каждом вызове будет обнуляться и я не получу возврат в виде количества раз, которые сработает условие If

Comment: @Интик Все, я понял, о чем вы говорите, сразу не дошло)) Спасибо за помощь) Напишите это в ответ, я галочку поставлю

Comment: простите, я с телефона.не удобно оформлять ответ, а неполный могут и заминусить.

Comment: Ничего страшного, если что - пишите, когда будет удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можем работать с самим числом, без преобразования в строку. Это можно сделать с помощью **целочисленного деления на 10**, а также брать остаток. Когда целочисленное деление на 10 дает 0, значит в числе 1 символ и может возвращать.

```
def R(number):
    if number//10==0:
        return 0
    res = 1
    while(True):
        res*=number%10
        number//=10
        if number == 0:
            break
    return R(res)+1
```